# No jQuery plug-ins, No jQuery UI, ... Only jQuery API

Tags: jquery

I'm building a website and in my registration form I'm struggling with jQuery validation. I need to validate name so it contains only letters. No jQuery plug-ins .. No jQuery UI

Comment: But the jQuery core doesn't include validation does it? What is your question?

Comment: Please choose useful titles for your questions. They should summarize your question. I gather this is a problem because you haven't asked any questions, only stated your requirements. There *is* no concept of "validation" in jQuery. Without a plugin, your only option is to roll your own, and writing it for you is not what Stack Overflow is for. Without at the *very least* seeing your form, there is absolutely no advice or help this site can offer.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a regular expression for this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('sfjd')
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"No jQuery plug-ins"*

But the jQuery core doesn't include validation, so you'd need one or another validation plug-in (possibly something you write yourself).

> *"I need to validate name so it contains only letters."*

Well you don't need jQuery for that. Just use a simple regex:

```
var name = // some string that you set somehow from what the user entered
if (/[^A-Z]/i.test(name)) {
    // validation failed: some non-letter found
}
```

The regex pattern `[^A-Z]` would match on any character *not* in the A-Z range, and the `i` flag makes it case insensitive. So just set the `name` variable with or without jQuery and you're good to go...